# storing elements of a loop as tables

Tags: r, loops

I have the following code:

```
# Example 1: Unlabeled Design
des <- rotation.design(attribute.names = list(
  Region = c("Reg_A", "Reg_B", "Reg_C"), 
  Eco = c("Conv.", "More", "Most"), 
  Price = c("1", "1.1", "1.2")), 
  nalternatives = 2, nblocks = 3, row.renames = FALSE, 
  randomize = TRUE, seed = 987)
des


#common = c("Reg_A","Conv","1")
choice.experiment.design<-des

cards<-list()
k<-1

questionnaire.mod<-function (choice.experiment.design, common = NULL, quote = TRUE) 
{
  nblocks <- choice.experiment.design$design.information$nblocks
  nquestions <- choice.experiment.design$design.information$nquestions
  nalternatives <- choice.experiment.design$design.information$nalternatives
  nattributes <- choice.experiment.design$design.information$nattributes
  attribute.names <- names(choice.experiment.design[[1]][[1]])[-(1:3)]
  my.design <- as.matrix(choice.experiment.design[[1]][[1]])
  if (nalternatives >= 2) {
    for (i in 2:nalternatives) {
      my.design <- rbind(my.design, as.matrix(choice.experiment.design$alternatives[[i]]))#
    }
  }
  if (is.null(common) == FALSE) {
    nalternatives <- nalternatives + 1
    common.base <- choice.experiment.design$alternatives[[1]]
    common.base[, 3] <- nalternatives
    common.base <- as.matrix(common.base)
    for (i in attribute.names) {
      common.base[, i] <- common[[i]]#
    }
    my.design <- rbind(my.design, common.base)
  }
  rownames(my.design) <- NULL
  my.design <- data.frame(my.design)
  my.design$BLOCK <- as.numeric(as.character(my.design$BLOCK))
  my.design$QUES  <- as.numeric(as.character(my.design$QES))
  my.design$ALT   <- as.numeric(as.character(my.design$ALT))
  my.design <- my.design[order(my.design$BLOCK, my.design$QES, 
                               my.design$ALT), ]
  #alternative.names <- paste("alt.", 1:nalternatives, sep = "")
  alternative.names <- paste("alt.", LETTERS[1:nalternatives], sep = "")
  
  cat("\n")
  for (i in 1:nblocks) {
    cat("Block", i, "\n", "\n")
    for (j in 1:nquestions) {
      cat("Question", j, "\n")
      temp <- subset(my.design, my.design$BLOCK == i & my.design$QES == j)#
      temp <- temp[, 4:(3 + nattributes)]
      if (nattributes == 1) {
        temp <- as.data.frame(temp)
        names(temp) <- attribute.names
        temp.dataframe<- t(temp)
        colnames(temp.dataframe) <- alternative.names
        # Save result
        cards[[i]][[j]] <- temp.dataframe#added to the code
        questionna   }
      
      temp <- t(temp)
      colnames(temp) <- alternative.names
      print(temp, quote = quote)
      cat("\n")
      
    }
  }
}


questionnaire.mod(des,common = NULL,quote = TRUE)
```

and this result:

```
Block 1 
 
Question 1 
       alt.A   alt.B  
Region "Reg_A" "Reg_A"
Eco    "Most"  "More" 
Price  "1.1"   "1.2"  

Question 2 
       alt.A   alt.B  
Region "Reg_A" "Reg_C"
Eco    "More"  "Most" 
Price  "1.2"   "1.2"  

Question 3 
       alt.A   alt.B  
Region "Reg_C" "Reg_C"
Eco    "Most"  "More" 
Price  "1.2"   "1"    

Block 2 
 
Question 1 
       alt.A   alt.B  
Region "Reg_C" "Reg_B"
Eco    "More"  "More" 
Price  "1"     "1.1"  

Question 2 
       alt.A   alt.B  
Region "Reg_B" "Reg_B"
Eco    "More"  "Conv."
Price  "1.1"   "1.2"  

Question 3 
       alt.A   alt.B  
Region "Reg_B" "Reg_A"
Eco    "Most"  "Conv."
Price  "1"     "1"    

Block 3 
 
Question 1 
       alt.A   alt.B  
Region "Reg_C" "Reg_A"
Eco    "Conv." "Most" 
Price  "1.1"   "1.1"  

Question 2 
       alt.A   alt.B  
Region "Reg_B" "Reg_C"
Eco    "Conv." "Conv."
Price  "1.2"   "1.1"  

Question 3 
       alt.A   alt.B  
Region "Reg_A" "Reg_B"
Eco    "Conv." "Most" 
Price  "1"     "1"
```

I would like that each of the questions (i.e. question 1,2,3...) is stored as a dataframe within the list "cards" I created (at the beggining of the code).
I am new to loops and so far I am unable to understand why my code is not working.

I changed a bit of the code and added this

```
        cards[[i]][[j]] <- temp.dataframe#added to the code
```

but still the results are not being stored in the loop

Comment: The code you shared is somewhat complex, but the question you have is pretty simple. Is there a way for you to simplify your code for demonstration? Also, it appears there may be something missing on this line: `questionna   }`? If you can't simplify your code, sharing example data would help too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could create a list `cards` containing `i` lists of `j` dataframes, where `i` corresponds to blocks and `j` corresponds to questions within blocks.

```
library(support.CEs)

des <- rotation.design(attribute.names = list(
  Region = c("Reg_A", "Reg_B", "Reg_C"), 
  Eco = c("Conv.", "More", "Most"), 
  Price = c("1", "1.1", "1.2")), 
  nalternatives = 2, nblocks = 3, row.renames = FALSE, 
  randomize = TRUE, seed = 987)

choice.experiment.design <- des
common = NULL
quote = TRUE
  
cards <- list()
blocks <- list()

nblocks <- choice.experiment.design$design.information$nblocks
nquestions <- choice.experiment.design$design.information$nquestions
nalternatives <- choice.experiment.design$design.information$nalternatives
nattributes <- choice.experiment.design$design.information$nattributes
attribute.names <- names(choice.experiment.design[[1]][[1]])[-(1:3)]
my.design <- as.matrix(choice.experiment.design[[1]][[1]])

if (nalternatives >= 2) {
  for (i in 2:nalternatives) {
    my.design <- rbind(my.design, as.matrix(choice.experiment.design$alternatives[[i]]))
  }
}

if (is.null(common) == FALSE) {
  nalternatives <- nalternatives + 1
  common.base <- choice.experiment.design$alternatives[[1]]
  common.base[, 3] <- nalternatives
  common.base <- as.matrix(common.base)
  for (i in attribute.names) {
    common.base[, i] <- common[[i]]
  }
  my.design <- rbind(my.design, common.base)
}

rownames(my.design) <- NULL
my.design <- data.frame(my.design)
my.design$block <- as.numeric(as.character(my.design$BLOCK)) #updated to all caps
my.design$task  <- as.numeric(as.character(my.design$QES)) #updated to all caps
my.design$alt   <- as.numeric(as.character(my.design$ALT)) #updated to all caps

my.design <- my.design[order(my.design$block, my.design$task, my.design$alt), ]
#alternative.names <- paste("alt.", 1:nalternatives, sep = "")
alternative.names <- paste("alt.", LETTERS[1:nalternatives], sep = "")

cat("\n")
for (i in 1:nblocks) {
  cat("Block", i, "\n", "\n")
  for (j in 1:nquestions) {
    cat("Question", j, "\n")
    temp <- subset(my.design, my.design$BLOCK == i & my.design$QES == j) #updated to all
    temp <- temp[, 4:(3 + nattributes)]
    if (nattributes == 1) {
      temp <- as.data.frame(temp)
      names(temp) <- attribute.names
      temp.dataframe<- t(temp)
      colnames(temp.dataframe) <- alternative.names
    } else {
      temp.dataframe <- t(temp)
      colnames(temp) <- alternative.names
    }
    # Print result
    print(temp.dataframe, quote = quote)
    cat("\n")
    # Save result
    blocks[[j]] <- temp.dataframe
  }
  cards[[i]] <- blocks
}
```

Comment: hi @Skaqqs  Im getting an error...Block 1 
 
Question 1 
       1       10     
Region "Reg_A" "Reg_A"
Eco    "Most"  "More" 
Price  "1.1"   "1.2"  

Error in `*tmp*`[[i]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: hi! (1) Try defining `cards` at the beginning of your script like this `cards <- list()` rather than the way you have it in your question. (2) Without example data, this is very hard to troubleshoot, so please consider sharing input data to accompany your code. (3) Please delete the "answers" you've made, and instead add those code chunks as an edit to your original question. This makes it much easier for readers/answer-ers to understand your question. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks I edited the code, and it includes the example data at the beggining, also tried adding the suggestion you mentioned # Save result
      cards[[i]][[j]] <- temp.dataframe , but I was getting an error. So I tried moving it and nothing happens.

Comment: I have updated my post @Harrison Jones to make it easier to understand

Comment: Hi @valeria, I've updated my answer. I removed the function wrapper so it is easier to observe the behavior of the code and troubleshoot. I highly recommend doing this whenever you're having issue with a function. Let me know if you have any issues implementing my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Skaqqs! That is exactly what I wanted to do, your code works perfectly

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. Feel free to accept the answer as correct (green check mark) if you'd like. This marks it as closed and makes it easier for future readers to find.